# update column in record with current timestamp on update of another column without triggers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with column1, dateColumn1, column2, dateColumn2, etc..
I want to automatically update the date columns with the current timestamp when the respective column is updated.

I know this can be done with triggers, but on mySql 5 I need super privileges to use triggers, and I don't have those.. is there a way to do this without triggers, but in the create table statement itself?

I know of ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but it refers to the update of the entire record, not of a particular column..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can modify all of the SQL inserting/updating data into this table then the only solution I can think of is some kind of daemon or cronjob that searches the table for out of sync rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could suggest that the triggers be written by someone who does have the privileges. Or ask them how to accomplish the task since you don't have the rights to do your job.